# Triggering Azure Function based on ServiceBus and writing back not working (Python)

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azureservicebus

I have a Python Azure function that triggers based on messages to a topic, which works fine independently. However, if I then try to also write a message to a different ServiceBus Queue it doesn't work (as in the Azure Function won't even trigger if new messages are published to the topic). Feels like the trigger conditions aren't met when I include the `msg_out: func.Out[str]` component. Any help would be much appreciated!

*__init.py*

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func

def main(msg: func.ServiceBusMessage, msg_out: func.Out[str]):
    # Log the Service Bus Message as plaintext

    # logging.info("Python ServiceBus topic trigger processed message.")
    logging.info("Changes are coming through!")
   
    msg_out.set("Send an email")
```

*function.json*

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "entryPoint": "main",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "msg",
      "type": "serviceBusTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "topicName": "publish-email",
      "subscriptionName": "validation-sub",
      "connection": "Test_SERVICEBUS"
    },
    {
      "type": "serviceBus",
      "direction": "out",
      "connection": "Test_SERVICEBUS",
      "name": "msg_out",
      "queueName": "email-test"
    }
  ]
}
```

*host.json*

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[2.*, 3.0.0)"
  },
  "extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
        "prefetchCount": 100,
        "messageHandlerOptions": {
            "autoComplete": true,
            "maxConcurrentCalls": 32,
            "maxAutoRenewDuration": "00:05:00"
        },
        "sessionHandlerOptions": {
            "autoComplete": false,
            "messageWaitTimeout": "00:00:30",
            "maxAutoRenewDuration": "00:55:00",
            "maxConcurrentSessions": 16
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your problem, it seems to be caused by the following error:

> Property sessionHandlerOptions is not allowed.

[image]

Deleting `sessionHandlerOptions` can be triggered normally.

Comment: I think so too. The documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#hostjson-settings says that "If you have isSessionsEnabled set to true, the sessionHandlerOptions will be honored. If you have isSessionsEnabled set to false, the messageHandlerOptions will be honored."

Comment: use bundle : 

  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.1.0, 4.0.0)"
  }

to use sessionHandlerOptions