# Azure Function with ServiceBusTrigger not firing when scheduled

Tags: c#, azure, triggers, azure-functions, servicebus

I have an Azure Function (~4) running in a Linux Consumption plan. It targets .Net 6. It uses a ServiceBusTrigger. The ServiceBus has two queues, qprocessing and qcomplete. The first queue, qprocessing, has several messages, which are scheduled for delivery to this function. The ServiceBusTrigger is not firing and the messages stay on the queue until I investigate why they didn't execute.

I use the explorer to peek at the messages. Then they fire. When the function executes the message is moved to the queue, qcomplete. The following examples show what I received in the complete queue.

1. "DeliveryDateTime":"2022-01-15T12:00:00","SendRequested":"2022-01-16T10:12:40.3301147Z"
2. "DeliveryDateTime":"2022-01-15T12:00:00","SendRequested":"2022-01-16T10:12:40.3285614Z"

DeliveryDateTime is EST. SendRequested is UTC as set by the function when it executes. These messages remained on the queue for 17 hours. And they didn't fire until I used the explorer to peek at them.

I've been noticing this issue of unreliable delivery when scheduling a message to be enqueued.

I have Application Insights enabled, and I see no errors or exceptions when I execute the following traces for the last three days.

```
traces
| where message contains '"state": "Error"'

traces
| where message contains "Exception while executing function"
```

The function executes, but I have to peek at the ServiceBus queue first.

Or I have to access the Azure function app's web site. Just showing the Azure function app's web site generates a result.

For now, I have a monitor running every 15 minutes, which accesses the function app's web site. It's the page that says, "Your Functions 4.0 App is up and running."

Comment: Do you have customizations on your host.json file? Which method are you using to deploy the function?

Comment: I have no customizations on my host.json file. I am deploying the function from VS 2022 as a Zip Deployment.

Comment: Updated my answer as I acquired more insight

Comment: When the messages are "stuck", does opening Azure portal and going to the function app ->  "Functions->your Function ->Monitor" start the processing of the messages?

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED

The problem is in the [Scale Controller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/event-driven-scaling#runtime-scaling) not becoming aware of your trigger **or having problems with it**.

Add the SCALE_CONTROLLER_LOGGING_ENABLED setting to your configuration as per this doc: [Configure scale controller logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2#configure-scale-controller-logs)

This will add in the traces table logging about the Scale Controller and you might see something like this

"Function app does not contain any active triggers", which indicates that when your app will go idle, the Scale Controller will not wake it up, not being aware of any trigger.

After the function is deployed there must be a [sync of triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-technologies#trigger-syncing) sometimes is automatic, sometimes is manual, sometimes it fails.

In my case altering the host.json file was the issue ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68146273/triggering-azure-function-based-on-servicebus-and-writing-back-not-working-pyth)) **and also** "leftovers" from previous deploys inside the storage account used by the function, both in [the Blobs and in the File Shares](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/storage-considerations) that gave different kind of problems but still they invalidated my trigger

In other cases is a mixture of [deployment method not triggering stuff](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/210), by design or by failure.